# What's the port left to the audio output?

Tags: mac-mini

I found a port left to the headphone output (the one plugged in with a cord with a green jack), right to the USB ports, and under the SD card slot. It has the same radius as the headphone output. What is it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the audio in port.

> [image]
>
> **Audio in/optical audio in port**
>
> The Audio In port accommodates both digital optical input and analog audio input.
>
> Analog audio line input is accepted through a 3.5mm mini phone jack. The sound input port accepts line-level stereo signals up to 24-bit stereo 44.1-192kHz sampling rate. It also accepts a stereo miniplug-to-RCA cable adapter for connecting stereo equipment to the computer.
>
> Optical audio input is SPDIF format and uses a standard TOSLINK cable with a TOSLINK mini-plug adapter, accepting up to 24-bit stereo and 44.1-96kHz sampling rate.

Source: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202638